# How do I pull data from firebase into android studio at the exact point in the code?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to pull data from firebase where the code is? I currently have valueEventListeners, but they all run after the code below them, thus invalidating the following code. I want to be able to pull a value exactly where the code is, not later.

As of yet, I have not found anything online about this.

A good example of my problems in the code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, final int position, long id) {

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final String uid = user.getUid();

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                cCESnapshot = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("currChallenges").child(challengeList.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, ChallengeView.class);
        intent.putExtra("snapshot", cCESnapshot.toString());
        intent.putExtra("name", challengeList.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

cCESnapshot is null because the intent runs before the valueEventListener.

Comment: You've to put the intent creation and the startActivity into `onDataChange`. You can't run network requests on the main thread/synchronised.

Comment: The intent works fine right now, unless by putting it on another thread the android call will run first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onDataChange()` is asynchronous, so the only way to use the retrieved data is inside `onDataChange()`, example:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            cCESnapshot = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("currChallenges").child(challengeList.get(position));

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, ChallengeView.class);
    intent.putExtra("snapshot", cCESnapshot.toString());
    intent.putExtra("name", challengeList.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an asynchronous operation, when the data will arrive, the `onDataChange` callback will be triggered. Your `startActivty` code will be executed sequentially and this is why you get no value in `cCESnapshot`.

Move the `startActivity` code inside the listener.

**But be careful**, because each time the `onItemClick` click listener will be called, you'll add a value event listener. That way, you'll have multiple calls to `onDataChange` in each click and so multiple `startActivities`.

Instead, i recommend using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` which will be triggered only after a single change in data.